# Date jquery function fails to work on table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

The logic is first select a start date in each row, then click the button, a result date will show according to the skip day. For some reason, my code isn't working, any thought? Thanks

```js
$(".add").on('click', function() {

  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  
  var start = $row.find('.date').val());
if (start) {

  var set = new Date(start);

  set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));

  $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"><button class="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"><button class="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Because you have an error in your JavaScript, thats why. Check your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `)` at:
`var start = $row.find('.date').val());`

```js
$(".add").on('click', function() {

  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  
  var start = $row.find('.date').val();
if (start) {

  var set = new Date(start);

  set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));

  $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"><button class="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"><button class="add" type="button">OK</button></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="3" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this `)` at the last of this line `var start = $row.find('.date').val());`

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai said the same thing

Comment: Yea but while my typing I dont know there is already a answer been posted.

Comment: No problem, it happens.